# "Ambiguous use of subscript" error while deploying - Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, web-services

I am getting "Ambiguous use of subscript" error while deploying app on phone.

I have a JSON response in the following format:

```
[
    { 
        "title":"G1",
        …
    },
    {
        "title":"G2”,
        …
    }
]
```

This is my code:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in // URLSession.shared().dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) is now URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error)

        if error != nil {

            print(error)

        } else {

            if let urlContent = data {

                do {

                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject


                    for index in 0...jsonResult.count-1 {

                        if let item = jsonResult[index] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                            if let loc = item["title"] as? String {
                                self.locArr.append(loc)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }

                } catch {

                    print("JSON Processing Failed")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

My error is coming on the following line:

```
if let item = jsonResult[index] as? [String: AnyObject] {
```

Please someone help me as I am working with json for the first time. I am not sure if my code structure supports the above json pattern. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `let jsonResult = try ... as AnyObject` => jsonResult is treated as AnyObject and does not support subscripting. Therefore do an optional cast of jsonResult to `[[String: AnyObject]]` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
```

you should cast your `jsonResult` as an array of AnyObject

```
guard let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [AnyObject] else {
  return
}
```